# Child container doesn't cover parent container entirely, leaving a tiny padding

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm trying to make a container with only 1 colored border by nesting 2 containers inside one another. It worked but somehow the child container doesn't cover the part it's supposed to entirely. Also, I don't know if it matters, but this is on flutter web

My code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
        color: Colors.teal,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
             color: Color.fromRGBO(162, 181, 183, 0.3),
             spreadRadius: 2,
             blurRadius: 30,
             offset: Offset(-1, -1), 
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 30.0, 15.0),
        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(3.0),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(3.0),
          ),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: SomeWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What I got:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Basically I want to remove that tiny padding on the right that is revealing the background color of the parent container.

Comment: did you try removing right padding `right: 0` ? I am not able to produce your issue. I am getting exact results, you are looking for, from your code. because **0** is still a value.

Comment: initially there wasn't that zero, i added it to emphasize that it doesn't do anything

Comment: @FaiiziiAwan the issue appears when the outer `Container` is small enough. If it is large (say, as large as the screen) the line is extremely hard to see (hence my conclusion about the border).

Comment: still not able to reproduce. I wrapped it inside sizebox of 50x50, but not able to see any line on right :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am very confused of how this question has gotten some answers and accepted one currently is to use `Container` inside of a `Container` with padding inside of a `ClipRRect`, while **you only needed one container to create one sided border**.

```
 Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border(
                      left: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.teal,
                        width: 3.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(162, 181, 183, 0.3),
                        spreadRadius: 2,
                        blurRadius: 30,
                        offset: Offset(-1, -1),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child:  someWidget
                ),
```

Other thing is that you can give a `BorderRadius` only to a unified border. If you need this, then use `ClipRRect`.

***Also note that accepted answer suggests using `ClipRRect` on top of other widgets, so it clips everything outside of it, thus it will ruin container's shadow.***

To wrap up for all elements that you wanted to have, you need: container with shadow -> cliprrect -> container with one side border -> child widget

```
Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(162, 181, 183, 0.3),
                spreadRadius: 2,
                blurRadius: 30,
                offset: Offset(-1, -1),
              ),
            ],
    ),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius:  BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  left: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.teal,
                    width: 3.0,
                  ),
                ),

              ),
              child:  Container(height: 200, width: 100, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I'm stupid enough as to not have thought of this earlier.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                border: Border(
                  left: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.teal,
                      width: 10),
                ),
                // color: Colors.teal,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(162, 181, 183, 0.3),
                    spreadRadius: 2,
                    blurRadius: 30,
                    offset: Offset(-1, -1),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 00.0, 15.0),
                margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),

                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(3.0),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(3.0),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: Container(),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Comment: Nice Post. Why does it need to use clip?

Comment: I used clip to give circular border to container and and changed the color only from left side of container

Comment: great Franken. @Fatima Then I think no need to use inner radius. what do you say ?

Comment: I forgot to mention, in case anyone encounters the same problem as mine, ClipRRect removes the shadow so you have to wrap ClipRRect with another container and set shadow for that one instead

Answer (score 0):

Make use of a Row() widget to place the thin blue line and the white Container() side by side. That should serve your purpose. You can make use of a Divider() widget for the thin blue line too.

Another way is to make use of Stack, and put those two containers on top of each other. You can specify the positions for both containers and thus there won't be any padding issues.